# Angular 2 GET parameters remains empty

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi i want to send parameters within a GET request but my search parameters remains empty, this is my code:

```
        private jwt2() {
        let currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
        console.log('current.token ' + currentUser.token);

        let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();        //PARAMS
        params.set('pageSize', '6');            //pageSize

        let headers = new Headers({ 'Authorization': currentUser });
        console.log("params: " + params);    //here I can see correct params

        return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, search: params });
        //  }
    }
```

I can see the correct headers in chrome but not search params:

```
search
URLSearchParams
paramsMap
Map(0)
size(0)
__proto__
Map
[[Entries]]
Array(0)
length(0)
```

If I don't set params and manually write param into search option like this:
`return new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, search: 'pageSize=6' });`
it works

Answer (score 10):

I've encounter same issue because I was not importing URLSearchParams.

```
import { URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
```

Without importing explicitly URLSearchParams it was compling fine  but the parameters request were empty.

Also notice  the RequestOptions property  **search**   is deprecated, You should use **params**  :

```
RequestOptions({ headers: headers, params : myParams })
```

in place of

```
RequestOptions({ headers: headers, search : params })
```

The solution to use **params.toString()** is  a good workaround  since   RequestOptionsArgs  could also   either a string or URLSearchParams :

```
export interface RequestOptionsArgs {
    url?: string | null;
    method?: string | RequestMethod | null;
    /** @deprecated from 4.0.0. Use params instead. */
    search?: string | URLSearchParams | {
        [key: string]: any | any[];
    } | null;
    params?: string | URLSearchParams | {
        [key: string]: any | any[];
    } | null;
    headers?: Headers | null;
    body?: any;
    withCredentials?: boolean | null;
    responseType?: ResponseContentType | null;
}
```

It  avoid the issue by passing a string. In this case there is not point to use a URLSearchParams.

Answer (score 1):

Try to retrieve the data outside of the function so when the component loads it will exist before the `Get Request` is called.

**Function To Set LocalStorageData**

```
private get currentUser(): string {
      return localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
    }
```

**Retrieve Data**

```
myCurrentUser = JSON.parse(this. currentUser);
```

**Get Request**

```
private setDefaultPaymentMethod(payid: string) {
        const params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
        params.set('currentUser', this.myCurrentUser);
        return this.http.get('Path/URL/End?point'
            { search: params })
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe((res) => {
                console.log(res);
            });
    }
```

Comment: My problem isn't currentuser, my problem is that pageSize param isn't passed into RequestOptions, so the get request can't see the correct params

Comment: Is page size param supposed to be without '6' So this instead 6 without the '' in other words, is it supposed to be an integer wherever it ends up but it is as string?

Comment: I don't think this is the set declaration `set(name: string, value: string): void;`

Comment: No I mean are you handling the code on the server it is getting sent to?

Comment: Also can you please check the network tab in chrome tools and click on the request then copy and paste the headers and the response tab.

Comment: It isn't a server problem, when I see the get request in chrome I see that my search params is empty so the server receive a get request without any params

Comment: Request headers `Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:it-IT,it;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
Authorization:Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJkYW5pZWxlIiwiaXAiOiI3OS4xLjMzLjEzOCIsImV4cCI6MTQ5MTMxOTMwNn0.FM5oS_9pcfWa0Dkp-EsPNI7uaZ_AgoBpS67OeOiYpUZPYETHbiP8YgG7ufBu4vO
Connection:keep-alive
Host:*
Origin:http://localhost:4200
Referer:http://localhost:4200/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.98 Safari/537.36`, the response isn't correct because no params passed

Comment: also notice the space between 4200/ User- I am not sure where the URL is coming from but you might make sure it is formatted correctly.

Comment: the space is correct, sorry what you mean for request tab?

Comment: Inspect element, Click Network, Then select the request in the screen to the left that you were making. in your case the get. Then when the get opens Check the headers tab and tell me the information in there. Under general the whole URL the method and the status code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
RequestOptions({ headers: headers, search: params });
```

because if I use a string like this

```
RequestOptions({ headers: headers, search: 'pageSize=6' });
```

it works and in chrome I see this RequestOptions:

```
{"method":null,"headers":{"Authorization":["Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJkYW5pZWxlIiwiaXAiOiI3OS4xLjMzLjEzOCIsImV4cCI6MTQ5MTM4MDIyMn0.Z9Y2l7-VDE_Rd8jEqhZ2Sdpx-is5nBeRamtkYrRtt_4oGWXomkhg6-ig87BL0PI5kL11sLf24lpytK8YDeiWMQ"]},"body":null,"url":null,"params":{"rawParams":"pageSize=6","queryEncoder":{},"paramsMap":{}},"withCredentials":null,"responseType":null}
```

If I use params my rawParams remains empty

Comment: Well this doesn't answer your question... you just further elaborate on your issue. Answers should provide the actual solution :)

Comment: Well, *IS* this an answer? From what I see, this is not an answer? Your params are still empty? Maybe I'm confused :D

Answer (score 1):

Try using **params.toString()**

```
const params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
params.set('_language', this.translate.currentLang);

return new RequestOptions({headers: headers, params: params.toString()});
```